# Cannot find package "." in .../vendor/github.com/godror/godror

Tags: go

I'm new to golang. I'm currently trying to use the godror driver to read from an Oracle db. I ran `go get github.com/godror/godror` in my project's root directory and am importing the library like so:

```
_ "github.com/godror/godror"
```

But, I'm getting the error

```
cannot find package "." in:
    /test_repo/vendor/github.com/godror/godror"
```

I believe my PATH is set up properly, as the "go" command properly returns the expected "Go is a tool for managing Go source code..." response.

Comment: Did you do the first steps in [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code), like `go mod init module_name`?

Comment: Just to be clear, what do you get from `go version`?
And if you're on Unix/Darwin (macOS)/Linux, if you type `printenv | egrep ^GO`

Comment: @DavidChase ```go version``` got me ```go1.15.7 darwin/amd64```

Comment: @JimB so, I'm actually working off of my team's repo so I cloned the repo into a custom directory

Comment: Did you get that error from the `go get` command, or from something else? the `go env` output might help here too.

Comment: I actually got the error when building my docker image. No issues/errors up til that point. Ran ```go env```, GOROOT is /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.15.7_1/libexec and GOPATH is /Users/rhv521/go

Comment: Then what was the exact command, and from where was it run? There should be a lot more output from `go env` than that, neither GOROOT or GOPATH are useful for figuring out a problem with your module, and we want the values from the same environment, which would be within the docker build environment if the error is from building an image.

Comment: My bad -- the exact command was ```docker build -t [app-name]``` and I ran it off the root directory. Is there a specific part of the ```go env``` output you'd like to see? There's too much to fit into a comment here. The last few lines are: 
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/0s/g4j8z72j3m51pqfp7h4_tmhw0000gq/T/go-build669665859=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"

Comment: We need the go commands, not the docker commands. You can update your question with the required information, and I suggest creating a [mre] with the docker files.

Answer (score 1):

I can't exactly replicate your issue nor have I seen such a weird error - but regardless, if you were following the current [go modules](https://golang.org/ref/mod) pattern you wouldn't have this issue to begin with.

You shouldn't run `go get` anymore to download modules to use for your programs. Instead, in the root directory of every go project, you'll run `go mod init [modulename]`, which will create a `go.mod` file for you. After running `go mod tidy`, it will download all the dependencies and generate a `go.sum` file containing the dependency hashes for you as well. Next, running `go build` will generate a binary that you can run. At this point, if you make changes to any source file(s), running `go build` every subsequent time afterwards will make a new, updated binary in the same directory.